# SSH-ing to local server using with port forwarding?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, port, iptables

I have 2 servers, both running Ubuntu 14.04. They have local network between each other and only 1st server have Public IP, but 2nd doesn't.

**My problem:** I'd like to access to my 2nd machine using SSH. At the moment, I do SSH to my 1st machine, then from there I do SSH to 2nd. Is there any way to redirect specific port from 1st machine to 2nd machine? I mean, redirecting specific incoming port to my 2nd server's local ip.

**Example:**

```
ssh user_at_first_machine@first_machine.com -p 22     # ssh-ing to 1st machine
ssh user_at_second_machine@first_machine.com -p 2222  # ssh-ing to 2nd machine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do a NAT at the first server.

```
    iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d <public ip> -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to <ip of server 2≥:22
```

To work, you will need enable forwarding packages at the server 1:

```
    sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

To persist it, add the following in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
    net.ipv4.ip_forwarding = 1
```

And make sure the firewall of the server 1 allows the traffic.

Comment: added this: iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p tcp -o eth1 --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.x, where x.x.x.x is eth1's ip address on server 1 and it seems to work now.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It needs NAT mapping to return.